# Extracting from Pydantic model into email body

Tags: python, email, pydantic

I have warnings from a multi-nested HTTP json response loaded into a Pydantic BaseModel called TWWarningsDetail

```
class TWWarningsDetail(BaseModel):
    type: Optional[str]
    message: Optional[str]
    list: Optional[list[str]]
```

I have two types of warning from the response.
'duplicate_school_ids'
'missing_students'

Here is what the raw json looks like.

```
"warnings":{
                    "terms":[],
                    "teachers":[],
                    "courses":[],
                    "enrollments":[
                        {
                            "type":"duplicate_school_ids",
                            "message":"The following school ids are connected to multiple students and were ignored",
                            "list":[
                                "123456",
                                "987654",
                                "367854"                                
                            ]
                        },  
                        {
                            "type":"missing_students",
                            "message":"The following Students were not found in the school's students list and were ignored.",
                            "list":[
                                "226535",
                                "998877"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
```

Both are captured using the following code snippet.

```
if validate_response.enrollments:
                for enrollment in validate_response.enrollments:
                    logger.debug(enrollment)
                    email_body += f"\nWarnings:{enrollment}"
```

This is the result captured in the model.

```
Warnings: terms=[] teachers=[] courses=[] enrollments=[TWWarningsDetail(type='duplicate_school_ids', message='The following school ids are connected to multiple students and were ignored', list=[123456', '987654', '367854]), TWWarningsDetail(type='missing_students', message="The following Students were not found in the school's students list and were ignored.", list=['226535', '998877'])]
```

I am trying to find the best way to extract this and prettify it into an email body.  Sending the data via email in the current format would not be welcome.  It looks like this by dumping the whole enrollment object into email_body....

> Data has been sent with warnings.
>
> Warnings:type='duplicate_school_ids' message='The following school ids
> are connected to multiple students and were ignored' list=['123456',
> '987654', '367854'] Warnings:type='missing_students' message="The
> following Students were not found in the school's students list and
> were ignored." list=['226535', '998877']

I'd rather send it looking somewhat like...

Warning:duplicate_school_ids
Message:The following school ids are connected to multiple students and were ignored.

Student ID  123456
Student ID  987654
Student ID  367854

Warning:missing_students
Message:The following Students were not found in the school's students list and were ignored.

Student ID  226535
Student ID  998877

Maybe even wrapping a table around each one so the user knowns there are two distinct warning types.

Any reccomendations are welcome.